# How do I build projects to multiple outputs using FAKE?

Tags: f#-fake

Usually the solutions I make contains multiple applications, it could be a web-app, service and maybe a simple console app.

To build my projects I use:

```
let projects = !! "src/**/*.csproj" -- "src/**/*.Tests.csproj"
```

and then

```
projects
|> MSBuildRelease buildDir "ResolveReferences;Build"
```

The problem with this is that all my service dlls and console dlls end up in the same directory, `buildDir`, is there a way to force each project to have a subfolder inside the `buildDir`? For web projects it looks to be fine since there I have the `_PublishedWebsites` folder to rely on.

Also, when building it this way, doesn't that open up for some projects to be built multiple times? I mean, if both `Service` and `Web` have a reference to `LibA`, won't this end up with building `LibA` three times? One time it matches the file pattern itself and two times because of the references from `Web` and `Service`.

**UPDATE:**

It is for a demo project and you can find the code here: https://github.com/mastoj/FAKESimpleDemo

Comment: well no it should not build the dependencies multiple times (even VS won't do) - to your question: the easiest way would be if you would split your `projects` into various parts (I guess you already have some sub-folder structure under `src/`) and then do multiple `projects |> MSBuildRelease ...` - also don't you split the dependencies more? Usually you have multiple`Target` in your build script

Comment: Have you seen the [getting started](https://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/gettingstarted.html)? There it will split the output into `./build` and `./test` - so very similar to what you want to do

Comment: @Carsten, thanks for your comment. VS build dependencies if you build the sln, but here I match against every csproj and build that... doesn't that make each csproj be built individually? I do split into `build` and `test`. I guess splitting into multiple parts is the easiest thing to do, but it would be nice if you could be specify output based on project.

Comment: usually you even want everything into the same because the build is much quicker ;)

Comment: @Carsten, not sure what you mean with the last comment. Do you mean I want different project, I know I could do that but they are often very dependent of each other. Or do you mean that I should match all csproj and build them all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've must have been really tired when I did this, because it is quite obvious what to do. Instead of passing in all the projects right away I can just do the iteration myself and figure out what the output folder should be. So to resolve this I just added two helper functions:

```
let getOutputDir proj =
    let folderName = Directory.GetParent(proj).Name
    sprintf "%s%s/" buildDir folderName

let build proj =
    let outputDir = proj |> getOutputDir
    MSBuildRelease outputDir "ResolveReferences;Build" [proj] |> ignore

Target "Build" (fun() ->
    trace "Building again!"

    projects
    |> Seq.iter build
)
```

This way you will get one folder in the output directory per project built. The name of the folder is take from the parent directory name of the project file. You could probably use the name of the of the file instead if you wanted to.